# JMH does not run all benchmarks

Tags: java, jmh

In my JMH benchmark I have 8 benchmark methods, 4 out of which, are not run. What is going on there?

My snippet:

```
@Benchmark
@Warmup(iterations = 1, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 1)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Fork(0)
@Group(value = "g1")
@GroupThreads(1)
public void Benchmark_1A_profileAddLastRoddeList(
        IndexedLinkedListState state) {
    
    profileAddLast(state.list,
                   ADD_LAST_OPERATIONS, 
                   state.random);
}
// More 3 similar benchmarks as above sit here.
@Benchmark
@Warmup(iterations = 1, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 1)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Fork(0)
@Group(value = "g1")
@GroupThreads(1)
public void Benchmark_1B_profileGetRoddeList(IndexedLinkedListState state,
                                             Blackhole blackhole) {
    profileGet(state.list,
               GET_OPERATIONS,
               state.random, 
               blackhole);
}
// 3 more friend benchmark methods sit here.
```

More precisely, the methods that add data to the state list are run, but no the access `get` benchmarks. My entire project is [here](https://github.com/coderodde/IndexedLinkedListBenchmark/blob/main/src/main/java/com/coderodde/IndexedLinkedListPerformance.java).

Comment: Created a patch in https://github.com/coderodde/IndexedLinkedListBenchmark/issues/2, the problem is the line `.threadGroups(1)` but not sure why.